# jupyter notebook opens calibre

Tags: jupyter

I installed jupyter notebook, but whenever I open it (from terminal), I have to copy and paste the address (local host 888 or the like), and it indicates that need to open some html file, for which (in my case) opens calibre.

Trying to fix this, i read that maybe this has to do with config file or the fact that I'm running it as administrator. As for config file, i modified the line where it habilitates firfox (in my case) as browser, but it doesnt seem to work.

This is the terminal message:

```
[W 12:33:19.743 NotebookApp] Config option `use_redirect_file` not recognized by `NotebookApp`.
[I 12:33:20.047 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /run/user/1000/snap.jupyter/jupyter/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 12:33:22.626 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/daniel
```

so, all i want is that automatically opens on a browser tab. I'm using ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with python 3.10.4.
Any help would be appreciated. Even more so if its as simple as possible. Some posts are too specialized for me.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "running as administrator"? You shouldng/can't run Firefox as root, if that's what you're asking about.

Comment: Yes, i mean that when using terminal, i run it as root, that's what i meant. I run firefox as a normal user, that is, with a doublo clic on its icon.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs for the `jupyter notebook` command as well as `rustup doc` when you install calibre using flatpak. Installing it as an apt package fixed the issue for me.

Check if calibre is a flatpak package with

```bash
flatpak list | grep calibre
```

If the above command returns a non-empty output, note the location of your calibre library and uninstall it with

```bash
flatpak remove com.calibre_ebook.calibre
```

Finally install the apt package with

```bash
sudo apt install calibre
```

Open the newly installed calibre apt package and point it to your existing calibre library instead of creating a new one.